# MATLAB - properly defining function and running script

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a program for the Bisection method, but I am not fully understanding how to properly define a function and run the script. I have searched google and watched YouTube videos and MATLAB tutorials on this stuff, but I just don't get it. I hope someone here can help me once I present my code, and the error messages I am getting, as well as what I should expect to see...

**Code:**

```
function [f] = Bisection(a,b,Nmax,TOL)
f(x)= x^3  - x^2 + x;
i=1;
BisectA=f(a);
while i <= Nmax
    p=a+(b-a)/2;
    BisectP=f(p);
    if BisectP == 0 || (b-a)/2 < TOL        
        disp('p');
    end
    i=i+1;
    if BisectA*BisectP > 0
        a=p;
        BisectA=BisectP;
    else
        b=p;
    end
end
disp('Method failed after num2str(Nmax) iterations, Nmax=', Nmax);
```

When I run this code, I get the error message:

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'x'.
Error in ==> Bisection at 2
f(x)= x^3  - x^2 + x;
```

I am unable to figure out **how** to define 'x'?? Also, should I create more than one function? I would like to have them all in one file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You error is occurring because `x` is indeed undefined. If you'r trying to create an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) that takes `x` as an argument, you'd do that like this:

```
f = @(x)x.^3-x.^2+x;
```

Then you can call `f(a)` as you do later on. Another potential issue is that your `Bisection` function is returning `f`. Do you want it to return the function handle?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what function handle means. Would you recommend that my function doesn't return the f.h., or not?